# Why is the site icon "FOS", and should it be changed?

Tags: discussion, design

I expected that the icon would be "OS" - for Open Source - but it appears to be "FOS". I assume that this stands for some mash-up of "Free Software" and "Open Source", possibly stemming from [this discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20428/expand-name-to-include-both-free-software-and-open-source).

I'm not sure where I stand on the name-of-the-site issue, but I do know that, currently, the site name is "Open Source", and I think it makes more sense to make the icon "OS".

So, my question is twofold:

1. Why is the icon "FOS"?
2. Should we change it, at least for now?

Comment: OS is Operating System/s to me. Not Open Source. I acronymize Operating System/s, but not open source. I have read, a lot, FOSS for Free and Open Source Software and FLOSS for Free/Libre Open Source Software, though.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not too concerned, as these icons aren't that important anyway; we should be aiming for graduation where we'll get a properly designed icon.

Comment: You realize graduation could theoretically take 1.6k days? Solve this problem now, don't wait.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your second point: `Should we change it, at least for now?`

Yes. There's no `F` in our name, so why should there be in the logo? That `F` may be relevant as indicated by others, but it's also very confusing. As long as there's no `F` in our sites name, there shouldn't be one in the logo either.

Get rid of it.

Comment: OS is Operating System/s to me. Not Open Source. I acronymize Operating System/s, but not open source. I have read, a lot, FOSS for Free and Open Source Software and FLOSS for Free/Libre Open Source Software, though.

Answer (score 0):

My worry about the word "free" in the site description [attracting questions on software with no cost](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/free-software-in-the-description-please) doesn't apply to the letter "F" in the icon, so I don't have an objection here.

I'm not personally fond of either "FOS" or "OS" for the icon, so I have no preference.

Comment: I know that this isn't related to the site icon, but Free Software should have a reference here, as it comprises many open source traits, and there is an entirely related organization - the Free Software Foundation. I think we should have it, and with a wonderfully active community like ours, we can police this.

Comment: @Zizouz212 you can have your say on where/whether we should use the word free in the question I linked to - we need all the feedback we can get to see what the community prefers.

Comment: Yeah, I submitted an answer there just now :D

Answer (score 0):

**It should be changed to FLO** because "source" is a software term mostly and this is explicitly about Free/Libre/Open type issues for all sorts of works, not just programs.