# What should the Tour's '(Don't) ask about' section contain?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tour

In the [tour site](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/tour) there is a section 'Get answers to practical, detailed questions'. There are two lists: 'Ask about...' and 'Don't ask about...'. These lists can now be edited by the appointed moderators. We should do this, as the content of lists is outdated, for instance it currently talks about 'open source software' although our focus has already moved beyond software alone.

The current content is as follows:

Ask about...

> - Specific issues with open source software
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered

Don't ask about...

> - Anything not directly related to open source software
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> - Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

What should the new content of these two sections be?

Please note, that we can put other content than pure lists, but lists seem preferable.

We also have already a [Meta-post asking about the description on the same tour-site](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/q/477/55), please also provide your opinion about this.

Comment: I've customized the tour page. Please don't take the [status-completed] as that nothing else can be done. If you would like something to be changed, kindly flag the post requesting for an update.

Answer (score 4):

Any reason we shouldn't base it on [the on-topic page](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? I've made this community wiki, so (after discussing in the comments) edit this if you think it can be improved.

> Ask about...
>
> - real problems or questions that you’ve encountered
> - the history and philosophies of the FSF, OSI, CC etc
> - understanding, applying, and complying with Free & Open licenses
> - issues related to project management, such as collaboration, monetization, marketing and distribution
>
> Don't ask about...
>
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> - Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer
> - if you want to know how to use or participate in Free & Open projects.
> - if you would like recommendations for Free/Open software or media

Comment: Sure, start with the on-topic page. After all it should be consistent.

Comment: I think the first bullet-point "real problems or questions that you’ve encountered" is quite meaningless. That could mean anything and nothing. Otherwise I agree with these points.

Comment: I see one issue with the "Free & Open" though. We are going to have to define that in all tour and help center documents, otherwise, people might be confused as to what it implies.

Comment: @Ziz does this part of the tour support links?

Comment: @curiousdannii Nope, it is not supported at all. In markdown, and raw html. :(

Comment: Unfortunate, it would've been handy to put a link to a Meta post explaining the terms there. Others can discuss what they think, but I don't think it would be essential to define them there, because other things on the page will have shown the site topic before hand.

Comment: What we can do, is lead a link at the top of the tour page, or even simply define it, not necessarily in this section, but at the very top.